# Killing shell=True process results in ResourceWarning: subprocess is still running

Tags: python, subprocess

Following the advice from [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

I have a process that I start with the following

```
process = subprocess.Popen(my_cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

my_cmd is in the form of `some_cmd_that_periodically_outputs_to_stdout | grep "some_fancy_regex" > some_output_file.txt`

I kill the process with the following

```
os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

After killing, I get the following warning

```
ResourceWarning: subprocess XXX is still running
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: remove this damn `shell=True` that you probably don't need and it'll work... or follow the dupe link.

Comment: But that is exactly how I got this warning, by following the dupe link

Comment: oh, right. Lemme check. Have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25134985/6451573 probably better (I've tested it myself)

Comment: I still get the same warning.  I don't think this is a duplicate, since my question is asking why I'm getting this warning and what's happening underneath.  (though knowing how to solve it would be a bonus)

Comment: have you tried to remove `shell=True` ? I think it's useless. That would make things easier without a shell process in between

Comment: This question is a follow up to the question linked which specifically deals with the case of shell=True... the dupe link clearly does not explain the cause behind `ResourceWarning`.  I don't understand why this is still marked as a duplicate.  I'm not asking how to terminate a python subprocess with shell=True, I'm asking why, when terminating a python subprocess with shell=True, I get a `ResourceWarning`

Comment: Is `subprocess XXX` pid the same as `process.pid`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't `wait` for the process to end. Even if you kill the process, you're still supposed to `wait` for it so you don't have a [zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) hanging around. Python is warning you that you didn't `wait`.

Add a `process.wait()` call after killing it.